# MongoDB: How to increment a vector of integers by a delta vector

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a very simple document structure like:

```json
{
  "_id": "...",
  "vector": [100,50,4000],
  //...
}
```

I want to write an update statement, that changes the `vector` of a single given document id by a given delta (also a vector of integers). `[100,50,4000]` with delta `[-50,0,-2000]` would result in `[50,50,2000]`.

I also want the statement to fail, if the resulting vector would have any negative values.

How can I do this?

Comment: When you say _"I also want the statement to fail, if the resulting vector would have any negative values."_ do you mean you want a mongodb error or you want no update to occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using an update with aggregation pipeline. In order to update only the document with the matching id, you apply a filter for the `_id` field.

In order to be able to discern between not found and not modified (due to negative values), you apply an aggregation pipeline:

1. Calculate the new vector values and store it in the field `vector_updated`.
2. Check whether any of the values of `vector_updated` is less than 0. If yes, keep the `vector`field as it is; otherwise, assign the new values from `vector_updated.
3. Unset the `vector_updated` field.

This way, the result of the update operation returns 1 for `matchedCount` if a document was matched and 1 for `modifiedCount` if the document was updated.

This is a sample for the aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      vector_updated: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$vector",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [
                {
                  $add: [
                    "$$this",
                    {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        [
                          -50,
                          0,
                          -2000
                        ],
                        {
                          $size: "$$value"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      vector: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $lt: [
              {
                $min: "$vector_updated"
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          then: "$vector",
          else: "$vector_updated"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "vector_updated"
  }
])
```

See this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A-7YKqGOpUZ) to test.

Comment: For now I do something very similar to this. https://mongoplayground.net/p/C150ztkW335

But that leaves me with a problem, that I can't distinguish between the _not found_ case and the _result negative_ case :/

Comment: @DiegoFrings unfortunately, both $match and $redact cannot be used in an update pipeline. However, I updated the pipeline to be able to discern between not found and not modified.

Comment: That works like a charm.

Will use parts of @ray's solution and parts of your's. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of personal flavour, I find `$sum` a `$zip` vector a elegant solution. The idea is to create sum tuples through `$zip` and use `$map` to iterate through the sum vector and apply `$sum` on it.

[$zip](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) also allows you to handle exceptional case like lengths mismatch through parameters like `useLongestLength` and `defaults`

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: "..."
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "vector": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "delta": [
              -50,
              0,
              -2000
            ]
          },
          "in": {
            "$map": {
              "input": {
                "$zip": {
                  "inputs": [
                    "$vector",
                    "$$delta"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "as": "tuple",
              "in": {
                "$sum": "$$tuple"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7JeoSe2HvcW)

Comment: I like the map/zip approach. Will encorporate this into my solution. Thank you.